# Lambda vs LINQ- "Expression is always false"

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, resharper

I have the following code:

```
var thing = (from t in things
             where t.Type == 1 && t.IsActive
             select t).SingleOrDefault();

if (thing == null)
{
    // throw exception
}
```

`things` is a collection of Entity Framework Self-Tracking Entities

This works nicely, however I want to use a Lambda expression instead and changed the LINQ to this:

```
var thing = things.Select(t => t.Type == 1 && t.IsActive).SingleOrDefault();
```

Now Resharper is telling me `Expression is always false` for `(thing == null)`.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want:

```
var thing = things.Where(t => t.Type == 1 && t.IsActive).SingleOrDefault();
```

`Select` performs a projection (converting the type of the IEnumerable from `IEnumerable<Thing>` to `IEnumerable<bool>` with values `true` if `t.Type == 1 && t.IsActive == true`, otherwise `false`), then the `SingleOrDefault` returns either the only `bool` in this sequence, or the default value of a `bool` which is `false` if the sequence is empty. This can never be null since `bool` is not a reference type.

`Where` performs a filtering action (pulling out only those objects that meet a given criterion - in this case only selecting those where `Type` is `1` and `IsActive` is `true`), leaving the type of the IEnumerable as `IEnumerable<Thing>`. Assuming `Thing` is a class, the `SingleOrDefault` will return the only item in the sequence or `null`.

In either case, `SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception if the sequence contains more than one item (which is far more likely in the `Select` version!).